# Returning the biggest number in an array of Objects

Tags: javascript

im trying to figure out how i can return the most expensive price in this array of items.

```
let items = [
    {
      itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
      type: "book",
      price: 13.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Creation 3005",
      type: "computer",
      price: 299.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Finding Your Center",
      type: "book",
      price: 15.00
    }
  ]
```

I know the .reduce() method is specific for arrays. But im not sure what else i could use to determine what the most expensive price is.

I have also tried using Math.max() but im not quite sure how i would use it in this case

Comment: _"I know the .reduce() method is specific for arrays."_ This is an array. You can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Math.max(...items.map(item => item.price));
```

to get the highest price.

Comment: Good one , is it possible to get whole object of that max value.

Comment: @Afsar No, not with `Math.max`

Comment: I loved your solution. but if we want to show all the highest price details. then we have to see work around.

Comment: To return the whole Object of the max value, I believe that's where you would use the .reduce() method, correct?

Comment: @Afsar The question is the highest price from array of objects. If the question were object with highest price from array of objects I'd use `reduce` instead of `map` and no `Math.max`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const items = [
    {
      itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
      type: "book",
      price: 13.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Creation 3005",
      type: "computer",
      price: 299.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Finding Your Center",
      type: "book",
      price: 15.00
    }
];

const mostExpensiveItem = items.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const maxPrice = acc.price || Number.MIN_VALUE;
  if(item.price > maxPrice) acc = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(mostExpensiveItem);
console.log(mostExpensiveItem.price);
```

Using `for-loop`:

```js
const items = [
    {
      itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
      type: "book",
      price: 13.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Creation 3005",
      type: "computer",
      price: 299.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Finding Your Center",
      type: "book",
      price: 15.00
    }
];

let mostExpensiveItem = {};

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  const maxPrice = mostExpensiveItem.price || Number.MIN_VALUE;
  if(item.price > maxPrice) mostExpensiveItem = item;
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItem);
console.log(mostExpensiveItem.price);
```

Note: If you're only looking for the `price`, then, you can keep track of this property as a number instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `Math.max`

```js
let items = [
    {
      itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
      type: "book",
      price: 13.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Creation 3005",
      type: "computer",
      price: 299.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Finding Your Center",
      type: "book",
      price: 15.00
    }
  ]
  
  
const exp = Math.max(...items.map(({ price }) => price));

console.log(exp)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below snippet

```
let index,highest = 0;

for ( let item in items ) {
    if(items[item].price > highest ) {
    index  = item;
    highest = items[item].price;
 }
} 
// highest price item
console.log(items[index].price)
```